# How to create new object names from object data?

Tags: javascript

I need to create new data object from exist object.

I have an object that looks like the following:

```
var peopleObject = {
    "123": { id: 123, name: "dave", age: 23 },
    "456": { id: 456, name: "chris", age: 23 }
};
```

After rebuilding this object, I need to get:

```
var peopleByNames = {
    "dave": 123,
    "chris": 456
};
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.values` to get a list of values from the object and then populate an object based on the `id` and `name` of those.

```js
var peopleObject = {
    "123": { id: 123, name: "dave", age: 23 },
    "456": { id: 456, name: "chris", age: 23 }
};


var peopleByNames = Object.values(peopleObject).reduce(function(obj, value){
  obj[value.name] = value.id;
  return obj;
}, {});


console.log(peopleByNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let reconstructed = Object.values(peopleObject)
  .reduce((acc, x) => (acc[x.name] = x.id, acc), {});
```

Basically a one-liner.

Comment: Please add some details as to what you are doing.  Assume the OP does not understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.values` to convert the original object into an array. Use `map` and spread operator to loop the array elements. Use `Object.assign` to make new object.

```js
var peopleObject = {
   "123": { id: 123, name: "dave", age: 23 },
   "456": { id: 456, name: "chris", age: 23 }
};

var peopleByNames = Object.assign(...Object.values(peopleObject).map(({id,name}) => ({[name]: id})));

console.log(peopleByNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to get the required result.

**DEMO**

```js
var peopleObject = {
    "123": { id: 123, name: "dave", age: 23 },
    "456": { id: 456, name: "chris", age: 23 }
};

let result =Object.entries(peopleObject).reduce((r,v)=>Object.assign(r,{[v[1].name]:v[0]}),{});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```